# Duplicate rows because of null values

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have this query, which gives duplicated data. I know why, but can't find a solution.

```
"SELECT events._id, events.cusorabs, events.userID, events.date, events.status,   
events.comment, events.type, events.hours, customer.name, absence.name, customer.wbs, 
absence.code"+
" FROM Events, Customer, Absence"+
" WHERE events.userID = \""+userID+"\""+
" AND (events.cusorabs = absence.code OR events.cusorabs = customer.wbs)"
```

How can i use distinct on "events.name" and "absence.name"? Their values can become "null".

Answer (score 0):

Try using the 'group by' clause in sqlite

Answer (score 0):

You can give the columns new names during SELECT to differ between the two name-columns. For example:

```
customer.name AS customer_name, absence.name AS absence_name
```